# Custom format in Date in Angular using allocated symbols

Tags: angular, date

To display a Date with a custom format in Angular I use:
`{{myDate | date: 'MM.dd.yy hh:mm'}`

This will result in something like **11.09.19 05:30**, as you can see I can use spaces, dots and colons without a problem.

I would like to format my date as following **11.09.19 05H30**, the problem is that the letter **H** corresponds with the hour in 24-hour format so if I just use `{{myDate | date: 'MM.dd.yy hhHmm'}` I get **11.09.19 051730**, notice how the **H** can turned into 17 instead of just keep being an H which is what I wanted (although not the expected behaviour).

The quick fix I ended up with was splitting the date into 2 as following:

`{{myDate | date: 'MM.dd.yy hh'}}H{{myDate | date: 'mm'}}`

This isn't very pretty, and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it, found nothing on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `\'H\'`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxfbdc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
{{myDate | date: 'MM.dd.yy. hh\'H\'mm'}}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I was wondering if there was a way to escape characters but couldn't find info specific on this. Any reference to why this works so that I can better understand it and learn more?

Comment: @sgaleta I used it in my project, don't have any documentation link to share :( Please accept and upvote if this helped